# Is it ever safe to combine select(2) and buffered IO for file handles?

Tags: perl, io, buffer

I am using IO::Select to keep track of a variable number of file handles for reading. Documentation I've come across strongly suggests not to combine the select statement with <> (readline) for reading from the file handles.

My situation:

I will only ever use each file handle once, i.e. when the select offers me the file handle, it will be completely used and then removed from the select. I will be receiving a hash and a variable number of files. I do not mind if this blocks for a time.

For more context, I am a client sending information to be processed by my servers. Each file handle is a different server I'm talking to. Once the server is finished, a hash result will be sent back to me from each one. Inside that hash is a number indicating the number of files to follow.

I wish to use readline in order to integrate with existing project code for transferring Perl objects and files.

Sample code:

```
my $read_set = IO::Select()->new;
my $count = @agents_to_run; #array comes as an argument

for $agent ( @agents_to_run ) { 
    ( $sock, my $peerhost, my $peerport ) 
        = server($config_settings{ $agent }->
            { 'Host' },$config_settings{ $agent }->{ 'Port' };
    $read_set->add( $sock );

}

while ( $count > 0) {
    my @rh_set = IO::Select->can_read();

    for my $rh ( @{ $rh_set } ) {

            my %results = <$rh>;
            my $num_files = $results{'numFiles'};
            my @files = ();
            for (my i; i < $num_files; i++) {
                    $files[i]=<$rh>;
            }                 
            #process results, close fh, decrement count, etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code to show what you've done?

Comment: Added an example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `{ my $oldfh = select $rh; $| = 1; select $oldfh; }` is useless for read handles. That's a good thing, because if Perl emptied the buffer after every read as you seem to want, you'd lose data!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `readline` (aka `<>`) is quite wrong for two reasons: It's buffered, and it's blocking.

---

### Buffering is bad

More precisely, buffering using buffers that cannot be inspected is bad.

The system can do all the buffering it wants, since you can peek into its buffers using `select`.

Perl's IO system cannot be allowed to do any buffering because you cannot peek into its buffers.

Let's look at an example of what can happen using `readline` in a `select` loop.

- `"abc\ndef\n"` arrives on the handle.
- `select` notifies you that there is data to read.
- `readline` will try to read a chunk from the handle.
- `"abc\ndef\n"` will be placed in Perl's buffer for the handle.
- `readline` will return `"abc\n"`.

At this point, you call `select` again, and you want it to let you know that there is more to read (`"def\n"`). However, `select` will report there is nothing to read since `select` is a system call, and the data has already been read from the system. That means you will have to wait for more to come in before being able to read `"def\n"`.

The following program illustrates this:

```
use IO::Select qw( );
use IO::Handle qw( );

sub producer {
    my ($fh) = @_;
    for (;;) {
        print($fh time(), "\n") or die;
        print($fh time(), "\n") or die;
        sleep(3);
    }
}

sub consumer {
    my ($fh) = @_;
    my $sel = IO::Select->new($fh);
    while ($sel->can_read()) {
        my $got = <$fh>;
        last if !defined($got);
        chomp $got;
        print("It took ", (time()-$got), " seconds to get the msg\n");
    }
}

pipe(my $rfh, my $wfh) or die;
$wfh->autoflush(1);
fork() ? producer($wfh) : consumer($rfh);
```

Output:

```
It took 0 seconds to get the msg
It took 3 seconds to get the msg
It took 0 seconds to get the msg
It took 3 seconds to get the msg
It took 0 seconds to get the msg
...
```

This can be fixed using non-buffered IO:

```
sub consumer {
    my ($fh) = @_;
    my $sel = IO::Select->new($fh);
    my $buf = '';
    while ($sel->can_read()) {
        sysread($fh, $buf, 64*1024, length($buf)) or last;
        while ( my ($got) = $buf =~ s/^(.*)\n// ) {
            print("It took ", (time()-$got), " seconds to get the msg\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
It took 0 seconds to get the msg
It took 0 seconds to get the msg
It took 0 seconds to get the msg
It took 0 seconds to get the msg
It took 0 seconds to get the msg
It took 0 seconds to get the msg
...
```

---

### Blocking is bad

Let's look at an example of what can happen using `readline` in a `select` loop.

- `"abcdef"` arrives on the handle.
- `select` notifies you that there is data to read.
- `readline` will try to read a chunk from the socket.
- `"abcdef"` will be placed in Perl's buffer for the handle.
- `readline` hasn't received a newline, so it tries to read another chunk from the socket.
- There is no more data currently available, so it blocks.

This defies the purpose of using `select`.

[ Demo code forthcoming ]

---

### Solution

You have to implement a version of `readline` that doesn't block, and only uses buffers you can inspect. The second part is easy because you can inspect the buffers you create.

- Create a buffer for each handle.
- When data arrives from a handle, read it but no more. When data is waiting (as we know from `select`), `sysread` will return what's available without waiting for more to arrive. That makes `sysread` perfect for this task.
- Append the data read to the appropriate buffer.
- For each complete message in the buffer, extract it and process it.

Adding a handle:

```
$select->add($fh);
$clients{fileno($fh)} = {
    buf  => '',
    ...
};
```

`select` loop:

```
use experimental qw( refaliasing declared_refs );

while (my @ready = $select->can_read) {
    for my $fh (@ready) {
        my $client = $clients{fileno($fh)};
        my \$buf = \($client->{buf});  # Make $buf an alias for $client->{buf}

        my $rv = sysread($fh, $buf, 64*1024, length($buf));
        if (!$rv) {
            delete $clients{fileno($fh)};
            $sel->remove($fh);

            if (!defined($rv)) {
                ... # Handle error
            }
            elsif (length($buf)) {
                ... # Handle eof with partial message
            }
            else {
                ... # Handle eof
            }

            next;
        }

        while ( my ($msg) = $buf =~ s/^(.*)\n// )
            ... # Process message.
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, this is much easier to do using threads, and this doesn't even handle writers!

---

Note that [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run) can do all the hard work for you if you're communicating with a child process, and that asynchronous IO can be used as an alternative to `select`.

Comment: does it matter that I know exactly how much to read from the file handle select gives me? I read my hash, and then I read a number of files in determined by a value in the hash.

Comment: @Lomsky, not when using `sysread`. `sysread` will return what's available and no more. I'll add that to the post.

Comment: I mean, since I know precisely what is being returned on the file handle (and it's all being returned at once), does the buffer really matter?

Comment: @Lomsky, Your premise that it's all being returned at once is incorrect. You have no control over that. You know what was *sent*, not what was *received*. If you knew what was received, there would be no reason to use `select`.

Comment: @Lomsky, Added clarification that explains why it's safe to use your own buffers when I claim that "buffering is bad".

Answer (score 1):

After much discussion with @ikegami, we determined that in my extremely specific case the readline is actually not an issue. I'm still leaving ikegami's as the accepted right answer because it is far and away the best way to handle the general situation, and a wonderful writeup.

Readline (aka <>) is acceptable in my situation due to the following facts:

- The handle is only returned once from the `select` statement, and then it is closed/removed
- I only send one message through the file handle
- I do not care if read handles block
- I am accounting for timeouts and closed handle returns from select (error checking not included in the sample code above)